# onchange of option got this error in vue js

Tags: vuejs2

when i select option from dropdown it will show me this error

```
" Error in beforeDestroy hook: "TypeError: function () {
      src_instanceMap.delete(instance.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_UID__)
    } is not a function" "
```

---

code

```
<span v-else>
    <select v-model="grade" @change="onChange" class="field" style="width:40%">
        <option v-for="(item, key) in grades.data" :value="item.id"> {{item.name}}
        </option>
    </select><br><br><br>
</span>

  onChange(event) {
        this.$inertia.get('training?gradeId='+this.grade)
    },
```

[image]

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shell" style="background:#fff;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center;">Training</h1>
                <span v-if="grades.data.length == 1">
                </span>
                <span v-else>
                    <select v-model="grade" @change="onChange" class="field" style="width:40%">
                        <option v-for="(item, key) in grades.data" :value="item.id"> {{item.name}}
                        </option>
                    </select><br><br><br>
                </span>
                
                <div class="search-container" style="text-align: center;">
                    <inertia-link href="/training" style="float: right;">Back</inertia-link>
                    <form @submit.prevent="filterdata()">
                        <input id="search" class="field" placeholder="Search DeepRoots Training" style="width:40%" maxlength="255" type="text" v-model="request.filter['name']" >
            
                        <input class="btn btn-green" style="margin-right:2%"  type="submit" value="Search">
                        <input class="btn btn-green" style="margin-right:2%" @click.prevent="reset()" type="submit" value="Reset">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <span v-if="videos.data == ''">
                    <h5 style="color:red;">Videos not found for this grade!!</h5>
                </span>
                <span v-else>
                    <h1 style="text-align: center;">{{ videoTitle}}</h1>
                    <div class="container" style="display: flex; height: 100px;">
                        <div>
                            <br>
                            <ul id="playlist" v-for="(video,index) in videos.data" :key="index">
                                <div v-for="(view,key) in videoView" :key="key">    
                                    <span v-if="view.training_video_id == video.id">
                                        <div class="video-block" style="border-style: groove;background-color:powderblue;">
                                            <span>{{ index+1 }}</span>
                                            <span v-if="video.type == 2">
                                                <img :src="videoImage"  width="80" height="80" alt="">
                                                <span>{{ cleanAndTrim(video.name) }}</span>
                                                <li>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <button @click.prevent="changeVideo(video, index)" class="btn btn-green" >Choose Video 1</button>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <br>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <button @click.prevent="secondaryVideo(video, index+1)" class="btn btn-green" >Choose Video 2</button>
                                                        <br>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </span>
                                            <span v-else>
                                                <a href="">
                                                    <img :src="videoImage" @click.prevent="changeVideo(video, index)" width="80" height="80" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                                <span>{{ cleanAndTrim(video.name) }}</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div v-if="videoView == '' && index==0">
                                    <div class="video-block" style="border-style: groove;background-color:powderblue;">
                                        <span v-if="video.type == 2">
                                            <img :src="videoImage"  width="80" height="80" alt="">
                                            <span>{{ cleanAndTrim(video.name) }}</span>
                                            <li>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <button @click.prevent="changeVideo(video, index)" class="btn btn-green" >Choose Video 1</button>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <br>
                                                </ul>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <button @click.prevent="secondaryVideo(video, index+1)" class="btn btn-green" >Choose Video 2</button>
                                                    <br>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </span>
                                        <span v-else>
                                            <span>{{ index+1 }}</span>
                                            <a href="">
                                                <img :src="videoImage" @click.prevent="changeVideo(video, index)" width="80" height="80" alt="">   
                                            </a>
                                            <span>{{ cleanAndTrim(video.name) }}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                            <vue-core-video-player id="videoarea" :emit="['ended']" @ended="loaded" controls :src="src" ref="video" :autoplay=false></vue-core-video-player>
                            
                            <h1>About This Tutorial</h1>
                            
                            <span v-if="checkNextVideo == true">
                            <h1>Next video:</h1>
                            <div style="border-style: groove;background-color:powderblue; width:40%;height:40%;">
                                <span>{{ nextTitle }}</span>
                                
                                <button style="float:right;" @click.prevent="nextVideo(key++)">Watch</button>
                            </div>
                            </span>
                            <span v-if="checkNextVideo == false">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="space"></div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
import AppLayout from '../../Layouts/AppLayout'
import Pagination from '../../Pages/Common/Pagination'
export default {
    props: [
        'videos',
        'request',
        'grades',
        'videoView',
        'status',
    ],

    components: {
        AppLayout,
        Pagination
    },

    data() {
        return {
            key: 1,
            src: this.videos.data[0] == null ? '' : (this.status == '' ? this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[0].media['filename'] : this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.status[0]['training_video']['media']['filename']),
            secondVideo: this.videos.data == '' ? '' : (this.videos.data[0]['second_video'] == null ? '' : this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[0]['second_video']['filename']),
            videoTitle: this.videos.data[0] == null ? '' : (this.status == '' ? this.videos.data[0].name : this.status['0']['training_video']['name']),
            videoImage: this.$page.props.baseUrl + '/assets/images/img/video.jpg',
            nextTitle : this.videos.data.length <= 1 ? '' : this.videos.data[1].name,
            grade: this.request.gradeId,
            videoElement: null,
            end: null,
        }
    },
    
    methods: {
        changeVideo(video, index) {
            this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + video.media.filename;
            this.videoTitle = video.name;
            this.key = index;

            if(this.videos.data.length-1 == index) {
                index = 0;
                this.nextTitle = this.videos.data[0].name;
                
            } else {
                this.nextTitle = this.videos.data[index+1].name;
            }
        },

        secondaryVideo(video, index) {
            this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + video.second_video.filename;
            this.videoTitle = video.name;

            if(this.videos.data.length-1 == this.key) {
                this.key = 0;
                let index = 0;
                this.nextTitle = this.videos.data[index+1].name;
            } else {
                this.nextTitle = this.videos.data[index].name;
            }   
        },

        nextVideo(n) {
            if(this.videos.data.length <= n) {
                n = 0;
                this.key = n;
            } 
            
            this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[n].media['filename'];
            this.videoTitle = this.videos.data[n].name;
            this.nextTitle = this.videos.data.length-1 <= n ? this.videos.data[0].name : this.videos.data[n+1].name;
        },

        filterdata() {
            this.$inertia.get(this.route('training'), this.request)
        },
        
        onChange(event) {
            this.$inertia.get('training?gradeId='+this.grade)
        },
    
        loaded(event) {
            this.videoElement = event.target;
            this.end = event.target.ended;
            let index = this.key;
            
            if(this.end == true) {
                
                if(this.videos.data[index]['type'] == 0) {
                    if(this.videos.data.length-1 == index) {
                        this.key = 0;
                        this.videoTitle = this.videos.data[this.key]['name'];
                        this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[this.key].media['filename'];
                        this.saveVideoStatus(this.videos.data[this.key]);
                    } else {
                        this.videoTitle = this.videos.data[index+1]['name'];
                        this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[index+1].media['filename'];
                        this.saveVideoStatus(this.videos.data[index+1]);
                        this.key = index+1;
                    }    
                } else if(this.videos.data[index]['type'] == 1) {
                    console.log("its quiz");
                } else if(this.videos.data[index]['type'] == 2) {
                    if(this.videos.data.length-1 == index) {
                        this.videoTitle = this.videos.data[0]['name'];
                        this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[0].media['filename'];
                        this.saveVideoStatus(this.videos.data[0]);
                        this.key = 0;
                    } else {
                        this.videoTitle = this.videos.data[index+1]['name'];
                        this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[index+1].media['filename'];
                        this.saveVideoStatus(this.videos.data[index+1]);
                        this.key = index+1;
                    } 
                } else {
                    console.log("return");
                }
                //location.reload();
            }
        },

        ended() {
            this.videoElement.ended();  
        },
         
        saveVideoStatus(status) {
            this.$inertia.post(this.route('videoStatus') + '?gradeId='+this.grade, status)
        },

        reset: function () {
            this.$inertia.get(this.route('training'));
        }
    },

    computed: {
        // a computed getter
        checkNextVideo: function () {
            let arr = [];
            this.videos.data.forEach((video, index) => {
                this.videoView.forEach((view, key) => {
                    if(view.training_video_id == video.id) {
                        arr.push(video.id);
                    }
                });
            });
            
            if(this.videos.data.length == arr.length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    },

    created() {
        
        if(this.videoView == '') {
            this.grade = this.request.gradeId;
            if(this.videos.data != '') {
                this.saveVideoStatus(this.videos.data[0]);
            }
        } else {
            this.videoView.forEach((view, index) => {
                if(!view.user_id) {
                    this.saveVideoStatus(this.videos.data[0]);
                }
            });
        }

        if(this.status == '') {
            this.videoTitle = this.videos.data[0]['media']['name'];
            this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.videos.data[0]['media']['filename'];
        } else {
            this.videoTitle = this.status['0']['training_video']['name'];
            this.src = this.$page.props.baseUrl +'/storage/videos/' + this.status[0]['training_video']['media']['filename'];
            this.videos.data.forEach((video, index) => {
                if(this.status[0]['training_video']['id'] == video.id) { 
                    this.key =  index;
                } 
            });
        }
        
        if(this.videos.data != '') {
            if(this.videos.data.length-1 == this.key) {
                this.key = 0;
                this.nextTitle = this.videos.data[this.key].name;
            } else {
                this.nextTitle = this.videos.data[this.key+1].name;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
    #playlist {
    display:table;
}
#playlist li{
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:8px;
}

#playlist li:hover{
    color:blue;                        
}
#videoarea {
    align: center;
    width:800px;
    height:550px;
    margin:10px;    
    border:1px solid silver;
}

.space { margin-top: 900px; }
</style>
```

---

when i select option from dropdown it will show me this error when i select option from dropdown it will show me this error

when i select option from dropdown it will show me this error when i select option from dropdown it will show me this error

Comment: The error is in `beforeDestroy` hook. Please share your whole code.

Comment: @kissu please check updated

Comment: Could be nice to ESlint it (and fix the errors) and use some Prettier on top of it. :)

Comment: @kissu i didnt understand why this error coming.

Comment: Probably because you're using a beta version of Vue-DevTools. Revert to a stable version and the problem might go away. To check if this is the cause - temporarily disable the browser extension.

Comment: Try to format the code first, to make it understandable.